# how to show 3 fields in one row in WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am doing customization of WooCommerce but I want to show 3 fields in one row I have tried a lot but no success. I have pasted the image of current fields

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUWqh.jpg)

I want to show send amount, receive amount and provider in one row

this is the code about the custom field

```
    woocommerce_form_field('receive', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'required' =>true,
    'class' => array(
    'woocommerce-input-wrapper form-row form-row-first validate-required'
    ) ,
    'label' => __('Receive Amount') ,
    'placeholder' => __('Receive Amount') ,
    ) ,
   $checkout->get_value('receive'));
```

Comment: You can try one-page checkout plugin??

Comment: i want to do it customize i am not using plugin

Comment: Can you post the HTML structure of these fields and of their container?
Maybe you can achieve this with CSS.

Comment: these are woo commerce fields and the code above creates a field

Comment: No one can derive the HTML code and the CSS from your code snippet.